# Trying to get HTML image and text on same line

Tags: html, css, image, text

I an trying to have a website with an image and text. I tried using inline-block; inline; block; float; in tons of combinations and none of them work. I want the text on the left and the image on the right.

```css
#maintext {
  margin-left: 160px;
  width: 650px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="maintext">
        <br/>
        <br/>
  <p>
Sample text<br/>
Sample text<br/>
Sample text<br/>
Sample text<br/>
Sample text<br/>
</p>  
  </div>
  <img src="www.example.com/image" alt="Picture of something" style="width:200px;height:200px;">
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want the image first? Or the text

Comment: Please provide a better description and some kind of illustration if you don't have a working prototype!

Comment: Side note, it's `<br />` or `<br>`, but not `</br>`

Comment: I want text first

Answer (score 0):

You want the text to take multiple lines?
then do this

```
    <p>
text will take multiple lines.<br>
ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd<br>
dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd<br>
ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
</p>
```

add `<br>` to end of line

Comment: no, I just did a typo on the example code sorry. I just cant figure out how to get text and image on same line!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this ?

```css
#maintext img{
    float: left;
}
#maintext p {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="maintext">
  <p>
text will take multiple lines.
ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
</p>  
  </div>
  <img src="www.example.com/image" alt="Picture of something" style="width:200px;height:200px;">
```

If not say me, you want text and image on the same line?